# create jquery .click before elements exists

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have a jquery function for a list of links ( `<a href="#" class="paging">1</a>` ) that I create with `$(".paging").click(...`. The problem is that I call the jquery script.js on my main php file, while the links are create on a later stage.

How do I reparse my javascript file? Is there another way to do that, maybe create the jquery click function every time I create the links?

Comment: it is duplicated a thousand times, please google your question before you ask!

Comment: Amin, just use the close feature to indicate your suggested duplicate. No need to lecture. Oh, crap. I'm lecturing.

Comment: sorry, didn't know what to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("body").on('click','.paging',function(){
   //code here
});
```

*Note: also it is best practice to use closest parent (instead of body selector in the above case) that exists from the beginning and does not change in future.*